# cannot convert from Card to int

Tags: java, arrays, types, int

So I have this array of the type Card, lets call it CardDeck[] . I need to save the info from CardDeck[0] to use it later. I thought I could do the following:

```
Card memory = theCards[0];
    for(int i=0;i<51;i++){

            theCards[i]=theCards[i+1];
            theCards[51]=theCards[memory];
```

To me, what is happening is that first I create a new variable called memory of the "type" Card, and the info in theCards[0] gets copied to it.

Then every "card" gets moved one step to the left, for example Card that are in the 2nd spot gets moved (or copied rather) to the first slot, the 3rd Card gets moved to the 2nd slot, and so on, all the way until the 52nd card gets moved to the 51nd slot. Then the card which originally was in the first slot, which we saved to the `memory` moves into the 52nd slot.

However the last line doesnt work, it says `cannot convert from Card to int` and I dont get it, I dont use an `int` type, its all `Card` types so whats up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Card memory = theCards[0];
for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
   theCards[i]=theCards[i+1];
}
theCards[51]= memory;
```

You're are trying to use `memory` as an *index* into the array. An index is always an integer, whereas `memory` is an instance of `Card`.

When you write `Card memory = theCards[0];` you are saying that you want the card stored at position 0 in `theCards` and you want to assign it to a variable named `memory`.

If you were to say `Card memory = theCards[42];` it would be the Card stored at position 42 you want to assign to `memory`.

When you say `theCards[51]=theCards[memory];` you are trying to say that you want the Card at position some card and you want to place it in your array at position 51. But "position some card" does not make sense, `memory` is not a position, it is an actual Card. It is like saying to the grocer that you want ice cream number Sun Lolly. You don't want ice cream number Sun Lolly, you want the Sun Lolly.

Comment: Thanks.. Could you explain what it means "to use as an index"? When I see that line I think: the "info" that's in theCards[memory] gets copied to theCards[51].. But thats not true?